# Draw lines in specified intervals of x-axis using winforms chart

Tags: winforms, charts, line

I am trying to add multiple(?) `StripLines` to recreate both red Error Limits lines seen in the picture below.

I've been fidling with the `StripWidth`, `Interval` etc. and I can't seem figure out how to limit the length of a `Stripline`. Does anyone have an idea?

[image: Example]

Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using a simple Line Chart...

```
    ChartArea ca = chart4.ChartAreas[0];
    chart4.Series.Clear();

    Series s = chart4.Series.Add("Error Limits");
        s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        s.Points.DataBindXY(new[] { 0, 15, 15, 30, 30, 50 }, new[] { 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2 });
```